# Determining if a series is absolutely convergent or conditionally convergent without the usage of the limit comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Would the following series be conditionally convergent, absolutely convergent or divergent?

$$\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{k\sin{(1+k^3)}}{k+\ln{k}}$$

Whereas for sine functions in series like this, you can usually say that it just alternates between 1 and -1 but would this one do the same for $k\geq1$? I don't think it would so that would mean I can't use the alternating series test. Perhaps, then, the ratio test or some comparison test?

Comment: You know this question wasn't solved though.

Comment: @AusterTiger Did you verify with your instructor?

Comment: I can't. This question is in a test.