# Determine whether the series converges/diverges (difficulties with negative terms)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine whether the following series converges/diverges:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{k\sin(1+k^3)}{k+\ln k}.$$

The problem is with $\sin(1+k^3)$. It is also negative and so I do not know which test to use. I did not find any similar problem anywhere.

Could anyone give me a hint, please? Have a nice day! Thanks!

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to type math.

Comment: The same series has been discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2692776/determining-if-a-series-is-absolutely-convergent-or-conditionally-convergent-wit.

Comment: Yes indeed just discussed earlier, I thought this was a bit different but it is exactly the same. Read the comments to the answer.

Comment: @MartinR I made some hypothesis to deal with this task, what do you think about it? what strategy could bebused to prove that $\sin (1+k^3)\not \to 0$?

Comment: @gimusi: If I knew the answer then I would write an answer :)

Comment: @MartinR Then the answer is: we have no answer! :)

Comment: @MartinR Finally we have an aswer! :)